How to resolve the following AWS Glue error while writing to Redshift using Spark: "ORA-01722: invalid number"?
I am trying to read from an Oracle database and write to a Redshift table using PySpark.
# Reading data from Oracle
oracle_df = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", oracle_url) \
    .option("dbtable", oracle_table) \
    .option("user", oracle_user) \
    .option("password", oracle_password) \
    .option("driver", oracle_driver_name) \
    .load()

Selecting only a few columns:
selected_df = oracle_df.select("Col1", "Col2")

Printing schema:
selected_df.printSchema()

|-- Col1: decimal(38,10) (nullable = true)
|-- Col2: decimal(38,10) (nullable = true)

I have converted all the columns to string:
for col_name in selected_df.schema.names:
    selected_df = selected_df.withColumn(
        col_name, 
        coalesce(selected_df[col_name].cast(StringType()), lit(""))
    )

 |-- Col1: string (nullable = false)
 |-- Col2: string (nullable = false)

When I write the Dataframe to Redshift, I get the error o323.save. ORA-01722: invalid number.
# Redshift Connection Configuration
redshift_connection_name = 'redshift_connection'
redshift_connection_options = glueContext.extract_jdbc_conf(redshift_connection_name)
redshift_url = redshift_connection_options["fullUrl"]
redshift_user = redshift_connection_options["user"]
redshift_password = redshift_connection_options["password"]
redshift_driver_name = "com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver"
redshift_table = "test_schema.main_last"

# Writing data to Redshift
selected_df.write \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("driver", redshift_driver_name) \
    .option("url", redshift_url) \
    .option("dbtable", redshift_table) \
    .option("user", redshift_user) \
    .option("password", redshift_password) \
    .option("tempdir", "s3://glue-temp/") \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .save()

I have made sure the Redshift DDL:
CREATE TABLE test_schema.main_last (
    Col1 character varying(256) ENCODE lzo,
    Col2 character varying(256) ENCODE lzo,


ORA-01722: invalid number is ORACLE error caused by failed attempted conversion to number either explicite or implicite. What you do after (outside Oracle), in this case, is irrelevant. Your Oracle's Select command returned this error.
Where the error comes from:
# Reading data from Oracle
oracle_df = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", oracle_url) \
    .option("dbtable", oracle_table) \
    .option("user", oracle_user) \
    .option("password", oracle_password) \
    .option("driver", oracle_driver_name) \
    .load()

The above code runs "Select [column list] From oracle_table" statement in Oracle database and that statement errors as ORA-01722 Invalid number.
Possible solution:
Since the error is raised by reading data from Oracle, make sure you control what you are reading and how. Is it possible that you are loading the data from an Oracle view, not a table, it looks just like there is an error in the view definition and/or view data that you are reading from. If that is the case then it will be more complicated to solve this - unless you have access to the view.
Use query option instead of dbtable.
# Reading data from Oracle
# Use query option instead of dbtable
#
# query_0 test query to be sure that the logic works
query_0 = "select 'A' as COL1, 1 as COL2 from dual"
#
# query_1 reads original data
query_1 = "select COL1, COL2 from oracle_table"
#
# query_2 converts original data to char on Oracle db side
query_2 = "select To_Char(COL1) as COL1, To_Char(COL2) as COL2 from oracle_table"

oracle_df = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", oracle_url) \
    .option("query", query_2)\
    .option("user", oracle_user) \
    .option("password", oracle_password) \
    .option("driver", oracle_driver_name) \
    .load()

The goal is either to isolate "corrupted" data or to build a workaround (with Oracle's TO_CHAR() function) and get your data loaded.
Start with query_0 just to make sure that the structure, driver, connection and the logic works ok.
If you want to find out which column (if it is a column) throws the error,  start querying with just one column with original data and add the others (one by one) till it errors (query_1) meaning the column added last is corrupted. If all particular columns raise the same error then you are, probably, reading a faulty view.
If you want to load the columns data as strings then declare your query doing the conversion on the Oracle database side (query_2). Converted values should be ok, just take care of columns that could be of DATE or TIMESTAMP datatype in oracle. If this fails too, again, you are, probably, reading a faulty view.
Handle fetched data after they were successfuly loaded.
If you are still getting the same error then the problem is not in the data selected but, most likely, you are reading an Oracle view (almost sure it's a view) with an error not in selection list (the data) of the view - it is in some other part of Select statement such as Where or Having or somewhere else. To solve this someone should correct the view definition on Oracle side, test it and make sure it works ok.
Here are just a few common examples of Select commands ending with ORA-01722 error
-- depending on your data - explicite conversion
Select To_Number('a23') "COL_NAME" From Dual;
-- ORA-01722: invalid number

Select Cast('a23' as Number) "COL_NAME" From Dual;
-- ORA-01722: invalid number

-- depending on your data and/or data manipulation - implicite conversion
Select 'a23' * 3 "COL_NAME" From Dual;
-- ORA-01722: invalid number

-- depending on your db settings of NLS parameters - if decimal point is comma, but dot is used when selecting the data
Select '2.3' * 3 "COL_NAME" From Dual;
-- ORA-01722: invalid number

Dealing with DATE datatype and date manipulations or date math could also couse this error
FAULTY VIEW SAMPLE 1   ( COL1 data ) :

query_1 from above - select columns one by one till it errors
last column added ( COL1 ) is corrupted but you can fetch all the others

Create Table TEST_TBL AS 
    ( Select 'A' as A_LETTER, 1 as A_NUMBER, To_Date('01.01.2024', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as A_DATE From Dual Union All
       Select 'B', 2, To_Date('02.01.2024', 'dd.mm.yyyy') From Dual Union All
       Select 'C', 3, To_Date('03.01.2024', 'dd.mm.yyyy') From Dual
     ) ;
-- Table TEST_TBL created.
     
Create View TEST_VIEW AS
Select A_LETTER, A_NUMBER, A_DATE, 
       A_LETTER + A_NUMBER as COL1    -- expresion when run against the data will raise the error
From   TEST_TBL;
-- View TEST_VIEW created.

When you select any column except COL1 there will be no error
Select A_LETTER From TEST_VIEW;
/*
A_LETTER
---------
A
B
C         */

Select A_LETTER, A_NUMBER, A_DATE From TEST_VIEW;
/*
A_LETTER   A_NUMBER A_DATE  
-------- ---------- --------
A                 1 01.01.24
B                 2 02.01.24
C                 3 03.01.24  */

... when COL1 is selected the error is raised ...
Select A_LETTER, A_NUMBER, A_DATE, COL1 From TEST_VIEW;
-- ORA-01722: invalid number

FAULTY VIEW SAMPLE 2  ( Where clause ) :

query_1 and query_2 both raise error for every column selected
fault is not in the data selection list (it is in Where clause)
you can not fetch anything without intervention in view's code or maybe in underlaying table(s) data if the data are the issue

Create View TEST_VIEW AS
Select A_LETTER, A_NUMBER, A_DATE  
From   TEST_TBL
Where  A_LETTER + A_NUMBER > 1;
-- View TEST_VIEW created.

Selecting any column from such a view will raise the error.
Select A_LETTER From TEST_VIEW;
-- ORA-01722: invalid number

FAULTY VIEW SAMPLE 3 - with data issue  ( in column A_LETTER ) :

it could be usefull to know the data from underlaying table(s)
the row(s) and or column(s) with the issue could be  excluded
all other data could be fetched

If the underlaying table data is like below:
Select * From TEST_TBL;
/*
A_LETTER A_NUMBBER A_DATE
-------- --------- ----------
11               1  01.01.24
12               2  02.01.24
13C              3  03.01.24    */

... here A_LETTER column has values that could be implicitely converted to number (except the last row).
If the view is defined like this:
Create View TEST_VIEW AS
Select A_LETTER, A_NUMBER, A_DATE, A_LETTER + A_NUMBER as COL1  
From   TEST_TBL
Where  A_LETTER + A_NUMBER > 1;
-- View TEST_VIEW created.

... and if you try to select all the data - an error will be raised:
Select  A_LETTER, A_NUMBER, A_DATE, COL1
From    TEST_VIEW
-- ORA-01722: invalid number

... but if you know/suspect that column A_LETTER could have some incorrect data - you can exclude such rows and fetch all the remaining data (using ... Default value On Conversion error when attempting to convert char value into number)
Select  A_LETTER, A_NUMBER, A_DATE, COL1
From    TEST_VIEW
Where   To_Number(A_LETTER Default 0 ON Conversion Error) != 0
/*
A_LETTER   A_NUMBER A_DATE         COL1
-------- ---------- -------- ----------
11                1 01.01.24         12
12                2 02.01.24         14    */


I assume there is an issue with the conversion to string, try to use something like this:
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from awsglue.transforms import ApplyMapping

# Convert the DataFrame to a DynamicFrame
dynamic_frame = DynamicFrame.fromDF(selected_df, glueContext, "dynamic_frame")

# Apply the mapping
mapped_dynamic_frame = ApplyMapping.apply(
    frame=dynamic_frame,
    mappings=[
        ("Col1", "Col1", "string"),
        ("Col2", "Col2", "string")
    ],
    transformation_ctx="applymapping1"
)

# Convert the mapped DynamicFrame back to a DataFrame
selected_df = mapped_dynamic_frame.toDF()


Update1:
Please try to do the conversion something as follows instead of doing it on the PySpark side:
query = "(SELECT TO_CHAR(col1) AS col1, TO_CHAR(col2) AS col2 FROM oracle_table)"
oracle_df = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", oracle_url) \
    .option("query", query) \
    .option("user", oracle_user) \
    .option("password", oracle_password) \
    .option("driver", oracle_driver_name) \
    .load()

You can either use CAST or TO_CHAR as shown above for conversion.
Also, as I have said earlier - you need to make sure that the "numerical strings" are valid as given in the "Action" part of the initial answer below.
Initial Answer:
According to the Oracle documentation here's the cause and action to take for the resolution of ORA-01722 error:

Cause: The attempted conversion of a character string for column or expression to a number failed because the character string is not a valid numeric literal. Only numeric fields or character fields containing numeric data can be used in arithmetic functions or expressions. Only numeric fields can be added to or subtracted from dates. If "UNISTR" appears in the error message, the value is not compatible with the national character set and cannot be represented directly.


Action: Use the LIKE expression to identify the problematic value. Ensure that it contains only digits, a sign, a decimal separator, and the character "E" or "e", and retry the operation.

To summarize in context to your question, there is an error in converting the string to a number while you are trying to write the selected_df to Redshift.
Now please correct me if I am wrong, it seems like you don't want the conversion to happen at all. You want the strings itself.
So, to deal with it I'll refer to the Amazon Redshift docs moving on.
Possible solution: You can set the column type as follows as shown in Amazon Redshift docs here under Amazon Redshift integration for Apache Spark:

To set a column type, use the redshift_type field.

columnTypeMap.foreach { case (colName, colType) =>
  val metadata = new MetadataBuilder().putString("redshift_type", colType).build()
  df = df.withColumn(colName, df(colName).as(colName, metadata))
}

The above code snippet is in Scala so here's the equivalent PySpark I wrote:
for colName in df.columns:
    metadata = {"redshift_type": "varchar"} # can be {"redshift_type": "char"} or {"redshift_type": "character"} or try different types that might work
    df = df.withColumn(colName, df[colName].cast(StringType()).alias(colName, metadata=metadata))

Check the Redshift docs on converting the datatypes for more information. (Note: This documentation is for the Amazon Redshift JDBC driver version 2.1 - if required, please check the docs for the correct version as per your environment).
After doing this, you can try writing the dataframe again.
Additionally, just for the completeness of the solution - you can also check on column encodings here in the Compression encodings section in Redshift docs where it's mentioned that:

Columns that are defined as CHAR or VARCHAR data types are assigned LZO compression.


Why is it giving me an ORA error when m using a redshift driver to write?

Also i tried doing the conversion so that everything becomes varchar and there would not be any type mismatch error

when i print the column of the dataframe, it says everything is string print(spark_data_frame.dtypes). If everything is string, why invalid number error

@Shabarinathk Possibly, the driver is trying to convert the "numerical strings" to numbers. Digging into driver documents is needed to find the exact cause. So, either you need to make sure that the "numerical strings" are valid as given in the "Action" part of the answer or you need to follow the above steps to keep them as varchar. First, check if you are able to write the dataframe or not after following the above steps.

I tried running the Pyspark code snippet you sent, not able to write the dataframe

Forget writing the dataframe, I am getting the same error while printing the dataframe using df.show(). An error occurred while calling o105.showString. ORA-01722: invalid number

@Shabarinathk Understood. It seems like the issue is when you are reading the data from Oracle DB - the driver is doing something under the hood to cause this error. I will suggest you do the conversion at the Oracle end only - and just read the already converted data. I'll update my answer.

@Shabarinathk Any updates on this?
